# Firebase - How to make sure Authentication for an already authenticated user doesn't happen again?

Tags: java, android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I've been trying to get a fix on this situation for days now, and I can't seem to find a solution. So here is what I want to do:
I have an app which uses [firebase-ui-auth](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/auth/README.md) to authenticate users via email/Google account. As soon as a user is authenticated, I write the user's details to a Firebase database child '**clients**'. Now I want to make sure that the next time the same user logs in, his details should not be written to the '**clients**'. To do this, I created another child '**reg_clients**', to which I push EmailID of the user who has logged in before. 
Now, as there was no way in Firebase to search on the server side whether `currentUser.getEmail()` already exists in 'reg_clients', I use:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // user is signed in
                clientCompletedRegistrationReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(clientCompletedRegistrationValueEventListener);

                Log.d("in onActivityResult","user is:"+user.getDisplayName());
                Log.d("in onActivityResult","emailAddressList is:"+ Arrays.toString(emailAddressList.toArray()));
                Log.d("in onActivityResult","user.getEmail() is"+ emailAddressList.contains(user.getEmail()));

                if(emailAddressList.contains(user.getEmail())) {
                    Toast.makeText(NavDrawerActivity.this, "You're signed in again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Gets photoUrl when Google+ photo is set, otherwise returns null. Appending '?sz=100' at end gets a photo of 100x100 px
                    String photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl() != null ? user.getPhotoUrl().toString()+"?sz=100": null;
                    Toast.makeText(NavDrawerActivity.this, "You're signed in for the first time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    Client client = new Client(user.getDisplayName(),0,photoUrl,user.getDisplayName().replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase(),"Brooklyn,NY");
                    // User has just created an account, save his/her details to the 'Clients' child
                    clientDatabaseReference.push().setValue(client);
                    // When user is registering for the first time, pushes his/her email ID to the 'Completed Registration' child
                    clientCompletedRegistrationReference.push().setValue(user.getEmail());
                }
                return;
            }
        }
```

In the database, there is always (initially)

```
--reg_clients
 |
 ---K_3uY0-M4ZCkRSt53SZ: "xyz@gmail.com"
```

But still the log shows
`in onActivityResult user is:XYZ`
`emailAddressList is:[]`
`user.getEmail() isfalse`

Due to this condition being **false** the data gets pushed to both the `clients` and `reg_clients` as new data, and thus multiple entries of the same user is being made in the database.

And then `onDataChange` of [clientCompletedRegistrationValueEventListener](https://gist.github.com/gamebusterz/43df706ef2f4fce68040142458ca8ba1) is invoked which populates the `emailAddressList`, but it has no purpose now, as duplicate entry has already been made.

**Please help me in this approach or please let me know if you have a better way to do this. Thanks**

Edit: Added code for `clientCompletedRegistrationValueEventListener`

```
clientCompletedRegistrationValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot emailSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Log.d("Adding",emailSnapshot.getValue().toString()+" to emailAddressList");
                    emailAddressList.add(emailSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    Log.d("in onDataChange","emailAddressList is:"+Arrays.toString(emailAddressList.toArray()));
                }
            }
```

Comment: where you are storing data into emailAddressList

Comment: @SaurabhPadwekar It's a global variable that I am using in that Activity. I am not persisting it anywhere locally, because `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` should  give me all the email addresses stored in the 'registered_clients' child.

Comment: include the listener code here

Comment: I have it linked to a gist, but sure I can add it here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a listener you don't get the value immediately.You have to wait for the response.So ,Put that code inside onDataChange of the listener.Like this

```
  clientCompletedRegistrationValueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot emailSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    Log.d("Adding", emailSnapshot.getValue().toString() + " to emailAddressList");
                    emailAddressList.add(emailSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                    Log.d("in onDataChange", "emailAddressList is:" + Arrays.toString(emailAddressList.toArray()));
                }
                    Log.d("in onActivityResult","user is:"+user.getDisplayName());
                    Log.d("in onActivityResult","emailAddressList is:"+ Arrays.toString(emailAddressList.toArray()));
                    Log.d("in onActivityResult","user.getEmail() is"+ emailAddressList.contains(user.getEmail()));

                    if(emailAddressList.contains(user.getEmail())) {
                        Toast.makeText(NavDrawerActivity.this, "You're signed in again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Gets photoUrl when Google+ photo is set, otherwise returns null. Appending '?sz=100' at end gets a photo of 100x100 px
                        String photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl() != null ? user.getPhotoUrl().toString()+"?sz=100": null;
                        Toast.makeText(NavDrawerActivity.this, "You're signed in for the first time", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Client client = new Client(user.getDisplayName(),0,photoUrl,user.getDisplayName().replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase(),"Brooklyn,NY");
                        // User has just created an account, save his/her details to the 'Clients' child
                        clientDatabaseReference.push().setValue(client);
                        // When user is registering for the first time, pushes his/her email ID to the 'Completed Registration' child
                        clientCompletedRegistrationReference.push().setValue(user.getEmail());
                    }

                }
            };
```

Comment: alright, thanks for answering, let me try this and get back to you.

Comment: Where should I keep `clientCompletedRegistrationReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(clientCompletedRegistrationValueEventListener);` then, leave it as it was in `onActivityResult` ?

Comment: i added the closing brace for the for loop at correct place. Now it should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131736/discussion-between-yankee-and-saurabh-padwekar).